# DataTables.js Requested unknown parameter when adding row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a predefined datatable on my page that is populating from data with an ajax call. After these values are on the page the user needs an ability to add rows by clicking a button, kind of like an audit log. However, every time I go to add a row I get the error

> "DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown
>   parameter 'data1' for row 2, column 0."

I have been up and down the internet and cannot figure this out. Help please.

I have the table variable defined globally so everyone has access to it

```
var escalationTable;
```

and then a function that calls my ajax to populate said table.

```
 function populateTable(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7) {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                //data: id,
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                url: baseUrl + 'rest/partUrl/action?var1=' + var1 + '&var2=' + var2 + '&var3=' + var3 + '&var4=' + var4,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {


                        escalationTable = $('.escalationTable').DataTable({
                            data: data,
                            columns: [
                                {
                                    data: "data1" ? "data1" : null
                    },
                                {
                                    data: "data2" ? "data2" : null

                    }, {
                                    data: "data3" ? "data3" : null
                    }
                ],
                            bSort: false
                        });



                    }
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    showErrorMessage(request);
                }
            });
        }
```

html

```
<table class="table escalationTable col-md-12" style="width:100%;">
                                                                <thead>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <th name='esId' scope="col">#</th>
                                                                        <th name='esUser' scope="col">User</th>
                                                                        <th name='esDate' scope="col">Date</th>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </thead>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
```

and then my click looks like this

```
$('.assignToSelf').on('click', function () {
        var rowNode = escalationTable
            .row.add({
                "esId": 'ffffff',
                "esUser": 'dfsdfsdf',
                "esDate": 'fffff'
            })
            .draw(false)
            .node();

    })
```

Comment: It produces this error if the data source object for the row had no esId parameter or the data was null or undefined (from [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4#Parameter-is-a-string) ) You should check both clues..

Comment: @bigless I have read the documentation. I am passing string values...so that shouldn't be the issue unless I'm missing something.

Comment: can you show the `html` for your table ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam added html. It's a basic table....nothing special.

Comment: just wanted to see the exact number of columns in the header, so tell me what is  `data1`, `data2` and `data3` as you are defining the columns for the table the following way `data: "data1" ? "data1" : null` which will evaluate to `data:data1` always, and that is where it is raising the exception why are you doing this,is that even valid ? @zazvorniki

Comment: I wouldn't set the column to null and instead default to a valid type like an empty string or zero. I would even go as far as to not even use a ternary expression and let the data display as intended. If you can access the server I would handle making sure the data is correct there before sending it to the client.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Data1, Data2, and Data3 are all coming back from the ajax call to fill in the table. Yes this is valid I have this part working in many other places as well. This is not the part that is breaking. The part that is breaking is when you go and add a new row to the table.

Comment: @RickyM I have to have the turnary in there because it is an older database with some funcky data in it. I can not change any of this data before it comes to me, it would take years to go through 20 years of production data. The table can handle the null and displays it more gracefully than it does an empty string. I have tried both and the null seems to be preferable. However, this is not part of my question or the part that is breaking....

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question would be naming the fields in the add the same as the data that is going into the field. Not based on the name of the field.

```
$('.assignToSelf').on('click', function () {
        var rowNode = escalationTable
            .row.add({
                "data1": 'ffffff',
                "data2": 'dfsdfsdf',
                "data3": 'fffff'
            })
            .draw(false)
            .node();

    })
```